# Copy prevention of Excel file

Tags: excel, copy-protection

There is excel file with complex mathematical model. How to prevent file coping from client machine to other machines? Client have to run Excel and type coefficients into equations, then Excel computes result.

I think about VB extension or macros which checks MAC of network card or value in Windows registry...

Comment: Even if you protect the vba project file with the macros in it; it can be removed.  There is no real way to stop the Copying of a file unless you utilize permissions on the file via the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of securely sharing Excel w/o an intermediary application e.g. a WebApp.

If you have SharePoint host it via Excel services.

If you know ASP.NET or another Web language then write a simple calculator or use e.g. https://www.google.pl/search?q=excel+to+asp.net+converter&oq=excel+to&gs_l=serp.3.0.35i39j0l9.84291.85973.0.86694.10.9.0.0.0.0.595.1008.1j1j1j5-1.4.0....0...1c.1.51.serp..6.4.1005.XWeje4bO7mI